# applying Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to work through a homework set, and the one of the problems states the following inequity:

$|\int \prod_{j=1}^{2^n} f_{j}d\mu| \leq \prod_{j=1}^{2^n} (\int |f_{j}|{ ^2}^n d\mu)^{1/{2^n}}$.

How can I prove it? Applying Cauchy-Schwarz?

Thank you for any help

Comment: You need to give more detail. What is $f_j $? What sort of integrals are you working with? Riemann, something else?

Comment: We are working with Lebesgue integral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that

$-|f(x)| \leq f(x) \leq |f(x)| \implies -\int|f(x)| \leq \int f(x) \leq \int|f(x)| \implies |\int f(x)| \leq \int|f(x)|$

Then,

$|\int \prod_{j=1}^{2^n} f_{j}d\mu| \leq \int \prod_{j=1}^{2^n} |f_{j}|d\mu$

Applying the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality $\Big(\int f(x) g(x) \leq \sqrt{\int f^{2}(x)}\sqrt{\int g^{2}(x)}\Big)$

$\int \prod_{j=1}^{2^n} |f_{j}|d\mu \leq \big(\int\prod_{j=1}^{2^{n-1}} |f_{j}|^2d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{2}} \big(\int \prod_{j=2^{n-1}+1}^{2^n} |f_{j}|^2d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Applying it to each of the individual integrals on the RHS,

$\big(\int\prod_{j=1}^{2^{n-1}} |f_{j}|^2d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}
 \big(\int \prod_{j=2^{n-1}+1}^{2^n} |f_{j}|^2d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\leq$
$
 \big(\int \prod_{j=1}^{2^{n-2}} |f_{j}|^{2^2}d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{4}}
 \big(\int \prod_{j=2^{n-2}+1}^{2^{n-1}} |f_{j}|^{2^2} \big)^{\frac{1}{4}}
 \big(\int \prod_{j=2^{n-1}+1}^{2^{n}-2^{n-2}+1} |f_{j}|^{2^2}d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{4}}
 \big(\int \prod_{j=2^{n}-2^{n-2}+2}^{2^{n}} |f_{j}|^{2^2}d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{4}} $

Now because there are $2^n f_j$, we can keep "halving" the individual integrals until we reach integral of one ($2^0$) $f_j$ with Cauchy Schwarz as I did above. Iterated application should end up with

$|\int \prod_{j=1}^{2^n} f_{j}d\mu| \leq \big(\int |f_{1}|^{2^n}d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{2^n}} \times \dots \times \big(\int |f_{2^n}|^{2^n}d\mu\big)^{\frac{1}{2^n}} =  \prod_{j=1}^{2^n} (\int |f_{j}|{ ^2}^n d\mu)^{1/{2^n}} \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of Generalized Holder's inequality. See, for example, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiq0qfE2_XeAhWLMo8KHe-zDNMQFjABegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.emis.de%2Fjournals%2FHOA%2FIJMMS%2F26%2F17.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3GgOogQcE7bhWFp4Rx0B4g